# Does ag-grid-angular version 13.3.0 support row reordering (rowDrag, rowDragManaged)?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm stuck with a really old huge Angular project witch uses many legacy libraries. Specifically, it depends on ag-grid-angular@13.3.0. I want to make reordering of rows possible.

I tried using rowDragManaged = true in gridOptions but it's not giving any result. I'm trying to figure out whether verison 13 even supports this or similar option, but I can't find it anywhere in changelogs and documentation. I asked ChatGPT, and it says this version supports row dragging but I'm afraid it's mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, version 13 doesn't support row dragging.

You can search through the changelog versions for "drag": https://www.ag-grid.com/changelog/?fixVersion=16.0.0

It was added in version 16: https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/16.0.0/javascript-grid-row-dragging/

It may not be that much work to upgrade from 13.3.0 to 16.0.0. I recommend to do it one major version at a time and test carefully at each stage, you might have a few small things to fix each time. You can also just firstly try a test direct upgrade to 16.0.0 to see how broken things get.